# Angle in a triangle whose side lengths satisfy $\dfrac{3}{a+b+c}=\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+c}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Suppose that we have a triangle $ABC$ such that
$$\dfrac{3}{a+b+c}=\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+c}$$

What is the angle $\widehat{BAC}$ between the sides of length $b$ and $c$?

If $p$ is the perimeter, then $3(p-c)(p-b)=p(p-b+p-c)=p(p+a)$ if I'm not mistaken.
I have made only very little progress, so I would appreciate some hints. Thank you!

Comment: Take an equilateral triangle of side 1. It satisfies the equation. The angle is 60°. Is a proof needed?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: yes, but it may not be the only possible case. The equation is not symmetric in $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplying the both sides by $(a+b+c)(a+b)(a+c)$ gives
$$a^2+bc=b^2+c^2$$
Now consider the law of cosines.

Comment: Thank you! By the law of cosines, $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos(\alpha)=b^2+c^2-bc$, so that the cosine of the desired angle is 1/2, which yields 60°